# Couldn't find '' with id = when trying to add to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to add a skill to an employee through an employee_skill table form on the show page for employee , but get the following error every time I try to create it.

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in EmployeeSkillsController#create

Couldn't find Employee with 'id'=
```

Employee Show

```
<div class="section">
<div class="top-border left"></div>
  <div class="top-border right"></div>
    <h3> Add Skill</h3>
    <%= form_for([EmployeeSkill.new]) do |f| %>
    <%= @employee.name%>
<div class="field">
     <%= f.label :Skill %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :skill_id, Skill.all, :id, :skillType, :prompt => "Select skill" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.label:skillLevel%>
    <% stars = [1,2,3,4,5] %>
    <% stars.each do |star| %>
        <%= f.radio_button :skillLevel,star%> <%= star%>
    <%end%>
    </br>
    <%= button_to "Add Skill", employee_skills_path(employee_id: @employee.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %> 
    </form>
</div>
<%end%>
```

Employee Skills Controller

```
  # POST /employee_skills
  # POST /employee_skills.json
  def create

    @employee_skill = EmployeeSkill.new
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id]) 
    @employee_skill.employee_id= @employee.id


    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee_skill.save
        #session[:employee_id] = nil
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee skill was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @employee_skill }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @employee_skill.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**UPDATE**

log file

```
Started POST "/employee_skills" for ::1 at 2017-04-26 12:35:38 +0100
Processing by EmployeeSkillsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bJ/wgo1Iz7KqLDtijEZ/emuWTuS4UblMlVnz7SyBZUSR7MJlxAmtXk5LS661t6598WfnCycDf6LtUHwhTOf9hQ==", "employee_skill"=>{"skill_id"=>"1", "skillLevel"=>"3"}}
  [1m[35mEmployee Load (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mEmployee Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Employee with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/employee_skills_controller.rb:31:in `create'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (12.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (292.9ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (485.7ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (885.4ms)
```

Comment: Post the parameters being sent to your create action from your log.

Comment: Added log to the question

Comment: `params[:employee_id]` is nowhere in the parameters, that's why this happens.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm trying to take the employee id from the show page the user is on.

Comment: You're not submitting an employee id in your params.  You're only params are "employee_skill"=>{"skill_id"=>"1", "skillLevel"=>"3"}

Comment: Any thoughts on how to pass it through? I thought i was passing it through on the button click

Comment: Your form doesn't have a submit button? There is also no need for the `</form>` tag, `form_for` takes care of that for you.

Comment: I meant on the button_to button, thanks i'll take that out now

Answer (score 1):

Initialize  an instance of `EmployeeSkill` in `show` action

```
@employee = Employee.find(params[:id]) 
@employee_skill = @employee.employee_skills.new
# The above statement will set :employee_id with employee's id
```

And then use it in form

```
<%= form_for([@employee, @employee_skill]) do |f| %>
```

You can also explicitly pass the `:url` if its not generated properly

```
<%= form_for([@employee, @employee_skill], url: employee_employee_skills_path(@employee)) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Just got around to trying this now getting a "undefined method `employee_employee_skills_path' for #<#<Class:0x8cde760>:0x884c520>" error

Comment: That was my guess for the route. You should check the route if it's correct or not

Comment: try running `rake routes` and use appropriate url

Comment: new_employee_skill_path GET /employee_skills/new(.:format) employee_skills#new                                                                                              I changed the rul to new_employee_path and am now getting a "No route matches [POST] "/employee_skills/new.1"", not sure why this isnt working? I see its a get but why is that?